# why does color white become gray?

Tags: java

i have an png image containg transparent parts and i want to make those parts white. Since i didn't find a way with the programs i have, i thought i just write a small programm:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\temp\\myimg.png"));
int w = img.getWidth();
int h = img.getHeight();
int white = new Color(255,255,255,255).getRGB();
for(int j = 0; j < h; j++) {
    for(int i = 0; i < w; i++) {
        Color color = new Color(img.getRGB(i, j), true);
        int alpha = color.getAlpha();
        if(alpha==0) img.setRGB(i, j, white);
    }
}
ImageIO.write(img, "png", new File("D:\\temp\\myimg2.png"));
```

but somehow the resulting image has the color 222,222,222 (alpha: 255) instead of white.
What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: Why you set alpha to 255 ? Why not 0 ?

Comment: Are you sure there aren't alpha values that are very small but not zero?  Maybe some pixels are `222,222,222,1` where the 1 is the alpha.  Also, what happens if you comment out the for loop so the image is just read and saved?  Is the output identical?

Comment: i checked, they are all 0 or 255. (i created a Set<Integer> and added them all, the result had only these 2 numbers)

Comment: So try commenting out the entire for loop so that the image is just loaded and saved.  Maybe that's what's changing pixels.

Answer (score 0):

There might be pixels whose alpha is not exactly 0 and rather a very small number like 5. so you are just replacing those pixels with alpha 0 which results in a shade of grey.

Therefore, try this and see if the result changes:

```
 if(alpha < 10) img.setRGB(i, j, white);
```

Comment: i checked, they are all 0 or 255. (i created a Set<Integer> and added them all, the result had only these 2 numbers)

Comment: ok then maybe in the empty area of your photo you have a mix of pixels with alpha 0 and 255 (alpha zero being in the majority). do a test. make a png file in photoshop with a square half color half completely empty and run your algorithm on it. if it works, what I said is correct and you need to restructure your code completely cuz it's not gonna work on that png file.